How exactly Typescript expects me to write a "number"?
Very short question.
<q-drawer v-model="leftDrawer" side="left" bordered content-class="bg-grey-2" width=100>
</q-drawer>

Using https://quasar.dev/layout/drawer/ 's width attribute, component's width expects a number, gets a number, and component works nicely, gets smaller/larger each time I change the number. But VSCode TS doesnt stop erroring out.

Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(3934, 3): The expected type comes from property 'width' which is declared here on type 'VNodeProps & AllowedComponentProps & ComponentCustomProps & QDrawerProps & Record<string, unknown>'
(property) QDrawerProps.width?: number | undefined
Width of drawer (in pixels) Default value: 300

How do I write a "number" to satisfy the check of Typescript? Just, how?
100

so this is not a number?
"100"

this neither?
{100}

so what is a number according to the Typescript?

:width="100" .

Try binding with a colon in front of the width, as in:
<q-drawer v-model="leftDrawer" side="left" bordered content-class="bg-grey-2" :width="100">
</q-drawer>

In HTML and Vue templates, when you set an attribute without binding it using v-bind: (or the shorthand :), its value is always treated as a string.

Docs - https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#passing-different-value-types

In the sense that Vue does a lot of the heavy lifting for you, then yes, it might seem like it's black magic.  Trust me, you don't want to do all that heavy lifting yourself.
